# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. React Native

Tags: react-native

I try to setState in compenetDidUpdate but it shows error infinite loop. Got any solution? Originally I put the setState in a function but also face this error. I am using class component code

```
 componentDidUpdate(){
          if(isEmpty(this.props.AESDetail) == false){
            if(this.props.AESDetail.length != 0){
              if(this.props.APIESDetail.length != 0){
                  if(this.props.APIESDetail.Focus != null){
                      this.setState({
                          gotFocusApies: true
                      })
                  }
              }
            }
        }   
      }
```

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might just need one additional test to make sure `gotFocusApies` isn't already `true`.

These if statements are also probably better off combined into one.
Note: `list.length != 0` can typically be replaced with `list.length` or `!!list.length`.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (
    isEmpty(this.props.AESDetail) == false &&
    this.props.AESDetail.length &&
    this.props.APIESDetail.length &&
    this.props.APIESDetail.Focus != null &&
    !this.state.gotFocusApies
  ) {
    this.setState({ gotFocusApies: true });
  }
}
```